# CSS transition if "position: relative"

Tags: css, web, css-animations

I need to animate a div from bottom to top, as shown in

http://jsfiddle.net/7En33/

However, the height of image and title is variable, therefore I can't use `position: absolute` for the `#content` section. How can I achieve this with `position:relative` and preferable without using Javascript?

Comment: if not javascript then why question is taged with javascript?

Comment: Preferable without Javascript.

Comment: CSS cannot do these things, it is not built for that kind of logic, the best you could try is to select the element you want perhaps with `document.getElementById('elementID').style.position === 'relative'` or something, then do the animation if so.

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by variable? Is it variable across many different pages, or is it variable on a single page? If it's the former, then it's possible. If it's the latter, then you'll have to use JS.